# How to interpret "Na dann haut rein"?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english, expression

This is from a work email, therefore I assume in a professional context:

> Na dann haut rein ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather colloquial, but thoroughly positive phrase that can mean things like

- Be well!
- Good luck and good bye!
- [Do your best, I hope you succeed!](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/reinhauen)

but also

- Go ahead, eat all you can!

depending on preceding context.

This combination in the given neutral, friendly or professional setting will never be used for the other translation coming up a lot for "reinhauen", namely to indicate an encouragement [to beat someone up](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reinhauen).

Comment: One could interpret it as *go back to work* also.

Comment: If you need an explanation where the expression may come from, imagine an animal (e.g. a tiger) hitting its teeth into the meat of its prey and thus 'doing the job' quite dedicatedly and energetically. At least that's how I would explain the birth of that phrase. I may be wrong, of course. It may also be rooted in the mining industry where workers are expected to hit the rock with their hammers or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

*Reinhauen* ist eine umgangssprachliche Beschreibung dafür, etwas mit Verve zu tun.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate it as: "Go for it!"